# eCharts - can we create a mekko chart using echarts custom chart functionality

Tags: echarts

eCharts does not seem to be having mekko chart out of the box.

Is it possible to create a mekko chart using e-charts custom chart functionality? Is it even feasible?

If anyone has an example/reference on this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Marimekko chart is very similar to [Profit chart](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-profit) from examples.